# spaCy Matcher: orange, apple and grape are fruits

Tags: spacy

I want to use spaCy matcher to match:

```
orange, apple and grape are fruits.
```

That is: `[NOUN[,and]]+ NOUN are fruits.`

However, my pattern is not correct. Could anyone help me write a correct pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet you have so far, and the output your incorrect pattern is giving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like spacy with `en_core_web_sm` identifies `orange` as `ADJ`. To check that, you run the code below:

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

for token in nlp('orange, apple and grape are fruits.'):
    print(token.pos_, end=' ')

>>> 'ADJ PUNCT NOUN CCONJ NOUN VERB NOUN PUNCT'
```

You can either try add entities and train it, or use text matching and handle `orange`. Really depends on what you are trying to achieve.